# What's the best way to publish a multilingual iphone game on the AppStore?

Tags: iphone, app-store

I'm close to publishing an iPhone game on the AppStore and I'm wondering what would be the best way to publish a multilingual game...

- Should I use the iPhone language settings to load the language accordingly?
- Publish multiple versions of the same game but in different languages?
- Put a setting on the game to change languages (or would users prefer not to use this one...) ?

Any ideas, recommendations, or best practices would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One app. Period.

Always use the user's current locale, and make a reasonable assumption for default in case you lack localizations users may be using. I've seen most commonly English be used as the default. Myself, I wouldn't even supply an override; the user has the device in their preferred localization already.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply @jer. Any ideas why games like angry birds don't use this approach?

Comment: I can't speak for Rovio on the matter, but as far as I know, they don't have different versions of the same apps for different languages. They have different versions for different devices/themes of the game.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely include all languages in a single app. You could set the default language to the language that the user has enabled on his phone and add an additional option in your app's settings.

Comment: but it's a very simple game... i would prefer if the player didn't had to do anything but play. I was asking before, any ideas why games like angry birds don't use this "all languages in a single app" approach?